# Converting an int to String in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_url = "https://swgoh.gg/db/missions/lightside/?stage=M0{}"
for i in range(1,10):
    my_url = my_url.format(i)
    print(my_url)
    print(i)
```

The variable i increments properly, but my_url always end ins stage=M01. Any help on fixing this to increment with i?

Comment: typo: use `for i in range(1,10):
    url = my_url.format(i)
    print(url)
    print(i)`

Comment: you are overwriting the variable my_url therefore the {} is deleted and the format does not apply, what you must do is create a temporary variable.

Comment: `for i in range(1,10): print('https://swgoh.gg/db/missions/lightside/?stage=M0'+str(i))`

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I feel pretty dumb about it. I just thought I had the python formatting off, but it was a lot simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to update `my_url` as in your case, in 2nd iteration  `format()` looks for `{}` inside new string and doesn't get it that's why it prints the same string obtained in the first iteration.

Please change your code like this.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    my_url = "https://swgoh.gg/db/missions/lightside/?stage=M0{}".format(i)
    print(my_url)
    print(i)
```